# Determine Exponential Equality Without Calculating Values

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

I want to determine the set of equivalent values in exponential form based on a series of bases and powers.  For example $2^k$, such that $2 \leq k \leq 100$ (ie, $2^{2-100}$) compared to $4^k$, $8^k$, $16^k$, $32^k$ and $64^k$.  There will be a lot of equivalent values (e.g. $2^6 = 8^2$, $2^4 = 4^2$, $8^4 = 16^3$, etc.).  I can brute force my way through this by identifying patterns, but I can't quite put this into a mathematical solution.  I would appreciate any help in moving toward that solution.

I'm not a mathematician (obviously), so I apologize for my lack of familiarity with proper form and appropriate markup on this site.

Comment: $$(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$$  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html

Comment: That's not my question.  The question is, does a^b = [b^a | b^c | c^a | c^b]?  I'm familiar with the laws, but unclear on which will aid me in this problem.

Comment: now I don't understand this $|$

Comment: It was supposed to mean "OR".  Does a^b = b^a or does a^b = b^c, etc.  I understand what you were trying to explain now that Ragnar has elaborated.

Comment: I failed to solve this correctly.  New question posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648919/problem-with-determing-equality-amongst-exponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k$ is fixed (later on, we will sum from $k=1$ to $k=100$). We know that
$$
\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}=\left(a^c\right)^b
$$
Now, we want all pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb N^2$ with $x^y=2^k$. We know that $x$ is a power of $2$, so $x=2^z$ for some $z\in\mathbb N$. Now, we want to find all pairs $(z,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $\left(2^z\right)^y=2^k$. Using the identity above, this simplifies to $yz=k$. Now, $y$ can be any divisor of $k$ and $z$ must be $\frac ky$. The number of divisors of a number is not really easy to compute, because you need the prime factorization of it. For $k\leq 100$, this can be done easily using a prime sieve.
Now, say
$$
k=p_1^{q_1}\cdots p_n^{q_n}
$$
then, the number of divisors of $k$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n (q_i+1)$.

I can expand this answer if you like. Please say so if needed.

**EDIT:**
If you want to find the actual divisors, I think the best way to get them is just by trial and error, because $k<100$.

For your example, $8^4=4^6$, you actually have $(2^3)^4=(2^2)^6$. This is true, because $k=3\cdot 4=2\cdot 6=12$. Other powers of two with the same value are corresponding with other divisor-pairs of $12$:
$$1\cdot 12=2\cdot 6=3\cdot 4=4\cdot 3=6\cdot2=12\cdot 1$$
The powers of two are:
$$
2^{12}=4^6=8^4=64^2=(2^{12})^1=4096^1
$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me make the connection from (a^b)^c to (a^b) = x and c = y, that makes perfect sense.  It's clear to me that 2^20 = (2^4)^5 = 16^5.  I'm not clear on the formula for the number of divisors.  I'm not looking for the number of divisors, I'm looking for the actual divisors.  I'm familiar with a prime sieve for determining prime numbers, but not for prime factorization.  Please give me some guidance there.

Comment: I'm having a hard time using this solution to determine that 8^4 = 4^6.  It makes sense when the base was 2 on both sides of the equation, but I can't make the jump to different bases.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying now.  Since 4,8,16,32 and 64 are all powers of 2, I just need to take the factors(divisors) of k and swap them between z and y in your example.  So take 64^8 = (2^log2(64))^8 = (2^6)^8 = 2^48.  48 is my k.  divisors of 48 (excluding 1 and 48) are 2,3,4,6,8,12,16 and 24. My set is then (2^2)^24, (2^3)^16, (2^4)^12, (2^6)^8, which would give me 2^48 = 4^24 = 8^16 = 16^12 = 64^8.  I suspect there is a relationship between the x and y in the form of x^y here, but I'm not exactly sure how that can be expressed in a formula.

Comment: @kakridge When $x^y=2^k=a^b$, the relationship is $y\log_2 x=k=b\log_2a$.

Comment: I think I just repeated what you said, but it is at least making sense.  One question, was I wrong about the log2(64)?  I assume this general pattern applies to bases of 3, 5, 6 and 7, correct?  Just log3, log5, etc.  I can't think of any other bases less than 100 that would yield many equivalents. True?

Comment: @kakridge, it is indeed similar for other (prime) bases.

Comment: By the way, you blew my mind with $y log2 x = k = b log2 a$.